# How to make other users have read access on a folder in my home?

Tags: permissions, 22.04, apparmor

My server is ubuntu22.04 and AppArmor is enabled. I want to share my folders (/home/syang/public) with other users. I give the read permission by `chmod -R go+rX /home/syang/public`, but they still cannot access this folder. It seems to be a problem caused by AppArmor. How can I add a file for AppArmor to allow others to access this folder and read files inside?

Here is the output:

```
ls -ld /home/syang /home/syang/public

drwxr-x--- 62 syang syang 4096 Jun 27 17:00 /home/syang
drwxrwxr-x  2 syang syang 4096 Jun 27 16:28 /home/syang/public
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the output of `ls -ld /home/syang /home/syang/public`.

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question and pasted the output. Does it help?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/437162/how-to-give-permissions-to-a-subfolder-while-denying-access-to-folders-above-it

Comment: in short: you need +x on the parent directory (/home/syang), otherwise other users can't see anything in it.

Comment: Thanks! it helps!